# How to build a viewpager that acts infinite and detects which side it was swiped?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I understand that a viewpager can be used, but I am having a hard time finding a good resource explaining how to use a viewpager with the following additions.

The view to record if the swipe was left or right, and either way just reload a new content (if left I want it to record no, right for it to record yes).

I want it to be infinite or really large, like 10000.

Finally, be able to add buttons underneath it as well.

In summary any direction, tutorials, or examples would be appreciated.

- *no tabs* - just avoided implementing a tab listener and including tabs when creating the view pager
- read swipes
- load new content
- infinite or really large
- *have buttons underneath it* - done by including it in the drawer layout

Hopefully this clears things up:

UPDATE: 
 Here is the scenario I am trying to read swipes - if left record no and if right record yes, then grab new content from cache and display it, with the same two swipe options, I was thinking maybe I can just have 3 "pages" and swiping left records the action then it resets to position (middle - 1) and then loads the next content available in the cache... the only thing is I do not know how to call the reset and ask for a refresh of the content...

---

EDIT:

No tabs has been solved by just adding the code like so:

```
//viewpager adapter
    private PageAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


// Initializing pager - in On Create
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.random_pager);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        mAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), new UserCreatedFragment(), new UserUpVotesFragment(),new UserDownVotesFragment());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // Here you would declare which page to visit on creation
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    private Fragment frag1;
    private Fragment frag2;
    private Fragment frag3;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment frag1, Fragment frag2, Fragment frag3) {
        super(fm);
        this.frag1 = frag1;
        this.frag2 = frag2;
        this.frag3 = frag3;


    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                //fragments should record no and reset to the same frag with new content back in position 1

                return frag2;
            case 1:
                //fragments for activity
                return frag2;
            case 2:
                //fragments should record yes and reset to the same frag with new content back in position 1
                return frag2;
        }

        return null;
    }


    //return count for number of tabs/swipes
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

xml of activity:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
        <!--View pager inside drawer so when opens it displays -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/viewPageLinear">
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/random_pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="300dp">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/no"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewPageLinear"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/no"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

xml of fragment loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/imagehere"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You mean, you want a viewPager without title indicating the position, and infinite Tabs?

Comment: Look at my edit, I basically Have an adapter, no tabs, no title. I am trying to do what I have stated in the adapter in the switch case

Comment: Look at the Konrad answer, use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to get the result you want. Post the xml where you have the ViewPager, i understand your problem but before answering let me see your xml

Comment: I added the xml and the scenario above, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html for reference.

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number
>   of pages, working more like a list view.

Other than that, it's not quite clear to me what the question (or the problem) is.

Comment: Thanks, Here is the scenario I am trying to read swipes - if left record no and if right record yes, then grab new content from cache and display it, with the same two swipe options, I was thinking maybe I can just have 3 "pages" and swiping left records the action then it resets to position (middle - 1) and then loads the next content available in the cache... the only thing is I do not know how to call the reset and ask for a refresh of the content

Comment: This is deprecated. You can use `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Tabs title in your ViewPager you have to add this inside your ViewPager.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/random_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And if you want infinite Tabs you should use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that is recommended when the number of Tabs is not specified.

Edit...

I've been looking a solution to your problem and this is what i found, if you want to know what direction user swiped you can do it this way, Implement `SimpleOnPageChangeListener` and on `onPageSelected` method do this:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
        onTabChanged(mPager.getAdapter(), mCurrentTabPosition, position);
        mCurrentTabPosition = position;
    }
};

protected void onTabChanged(final PagerAdapter adapter, final int oldPosition, final int newPosition) {
       if (oldPosition>newPosition){
         // left to right
      }
      else{
        //right to left 
       }

  }
```

Comment: I am not trying to have tabs or a title... I am trying to do the opposite, read the scenario above that I am trying to do

Comment: I've been trying to understand what you mean but for what i understand is: 
1- You want to reset content if user swipe to left?

Comment: I want to pull content if user pulls left or right, and just use the left or right swipes as a yes or no... i.e. the way tinder implements their swipes if you are familiar with that application